# Modifying the user role claims after login based on user selection criteria in a Blazor Server Side application

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

Good Day

I have a bit of an unusual situation that I am struggling to solve.

My application is a blazor server side using asp.net core identity as the user control.

What I need to achieve is that all users are set as standard users so that the can login. After login they are redirected to a company selection page. On selection of the company it is checked if in the DB the user should be an admin user of the company. if not an admin they are redirected to the main system.

However if they are supposed to be and admin in that selected company I need to add a role claim of "Admin" and then redirected to the main system.

I cannot seem to get this working. The closest I have got is that I am able to add the claim and its is visible in the AspNetRoleClaims table as well but is is not applied to the user as they are already logged in.

I tried to refresh the login, as well as attempted to logout/relogin the user but that's where it fails because the error is that the response has already been sent.

I also tried a service that uses IClaimsTransformation but i am failing to get that to work as well.

any assistance as to the correct methodology i should use and how to achieve this

Comment: See this question and my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076999/13065781.  It shows how to use a `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` that adds any roles you wish to an existing identity.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are building an ASP.NET Core Blazor Server application with user authentication using ASP.NET Core Identity, and you want to dynamically assign a "Admin" role to users based on their company selection. I can provide you with a high-level approach to achieve this:

1. **User Registration and Initial Role Assignment:**

   - During user registration or when you create a new user, assign them the "StandardUser" role by default.
2. **Company Selection Page:**

   - After a user logs in, redirect them to the company selection page.
3. **Check for Admin Role:**

   - When the user selects a company, query the database to determine if the user should have the "Admin" role for that company.
4. **Add Role Claim and Redirect:**

   - If the user should be an admin for the selected company, add the "Admin" role claim to their identity.
   - Redirect the user to the main system.

Here's some sample code illustrating how you can add the "Admin" role claim and redirect the user:

```cs
// Inside the company selection logic
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

if (userShouldBeAdmin) // Replace with your logic to determine admin status
{
    var isAdminClaim = new Claim("Role", "Admin");
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, isAdminClaim);
}

// Redirect to the main system
return RedirectToPage("/MainSystem"); // Or any other redirection logic you have
```

Now, addressing your issue of the claim not being applied immediately after adding it:

- Claims added to a user's identity are typically effective on subsequent requests, not the current one. After adding the claim, it won't be reflected until the next request or after re-login.
- If you want to force an immediate refresh of the claims, you can use the `SignInManager` to sign the user out and then sign them back in. Here's how you can do it:

```cs
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); // Sign out
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false); // Sign in again
```

Be cautious when implementing this because it might affect the user's current session. Ensure you handle any unsaved data or state accordingly.

Additionally, make sure that your claim checks in your application are correctly checking for the "Admin" role claim using `User.IsInRole("Admin")` or similar methods.

Remember to adapt this code to fit the structure of your Blazor Server application and its interactions with ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. On this line `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();` I get one of my previous errors of System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.