# Blazor Server, Scoped Service in Middleware not keeping data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

The data is not saved within a DI Scoped Service when using Middleware after Identity login. In this example, the data is always "false" even though it has been set to "true" (confirmed in the debugger).

I'm attempting to load the user's data in PostAuthenticationMiddleware.cs. I believe this is called after login.

How can I load the user data after logging in and retrieve it throughout the Blazor Server application?

EDIT #2: It appears that my approach of using app.UseMiddleware(); is incorrect. I've modified this to use a Scoped service that hooks onto AuthenticationStateProvider's AuthenticationStateChanged. I would expect this to fire when the User logs in, etc. However, this event is not firing. How do I get this event to fire? Or what is the preferred way to load user data from within Blazor Server after login? This data should be available throughout the application. I am assuming this should be in a Scoped Service.

LoginService.cs:

```
public class LoginService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    public string SomeUserData { get; set; } = ""; // We'll store data for the User here.
    public Guid TestUnique { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid(); // To check that this service is Scoped.


    public LoginService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        // Subscribe to the authentication state changes with the correct method signature
        _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthenticationStateChangedAsync;
    }

    private async void AuthenticationStateChangedAsync(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        // *** This isn't being fired ***
        var authState = await task;
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Load the user data from the database
            SomeUserData = "data from database!";
        }
        else
        {
            SomeUserData = "";
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the authentication state changes to avoid memory leaks
        _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= AuthenticationStateChangedAsync;
    }
}
```

Progam.cs (modified to include)

```
// ... template generated code
builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginService>(); // Added scoped service

var app = builder.Build();
// template generated code ...
```

Yet, AuthenticationStateChangedAsync does not fire. Why?

EDIT #1: I've tried saving the user details after login in MainLayout.razor, however this sometimes causes a race condition and the values aren't set before the target page is loaded. Where is the correct place to load in user related data after login in Blazor Server?

[image: Blazor Server setting a Scoped Service after login]

_Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Program.cs

```
using Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Areas.Identity;
using Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Data;
using Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserData>(); // added scoped service

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<PostAuthenticationMiddleware>(); // added middleware to fire event after login, this loads the UserData

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

UserData.cs

```
namespace Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Services
{
    public class UserData
    {
        public bool SomeUserData { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

PostAuthenticationMiddleware.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Services
{
    public class PostAuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public PostAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserData userData, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // User is authenticated; perform your actions here
                // You can retrieve the user from the UserManager using the user's name or ID
                var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Do we have any data?
                    if (userData.SomeUserData == false)
                    {
                        // We'll load the user data from the database.
                        // However... This is called 4 times.
                        Console.WriteLine("userData.SomeUserData is false");
                        userData.SomeUserData = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        // This is never called.
                        Console.WriteLine("userData.SomeUserData is true");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Counter.razor

```
@page "/counter"
@using Blazor_Identity_Middleware_Scoped_Poc.Services
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject UserData UserData

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Welcome, @user.Identity.Name!</p>
}
else
{
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
}

SomeUserData: @UserData.SomeUserData

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private ClaimsPrincipal user;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        user = authState.User;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the data? There's no attempt to set anything in any Blazor component. In Blazor Server the scope is the entire user SignalR circuit, which means roughly the user session unless there are reconnections. Despite the name `PostAuthenticationMiddleware` was only added as a middleware to the ASP.NET Core pipeline (which is still request based), not to the authentication middleware or SignalR

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to load user profile, settings or permissions, there are better ways

Comment: I'm attempting to load the user's data in PostAuthenticationMiddleware.cs. This is called after login. I want this data available on each page. What are the better ways?

Comment: @QiangFu well it's never going into PostAuthenticationMiddleware being True. So I think my understanding of app.UseMiddleware<PostAuthenticationMiddleware>();  is faulty. Where do I hook into the user being logged in?

Comment: You don't have to hook the login. One option is to customize the ASP.NET Identity model so that the data you need is loaded along with the user. Another option is to create a standalone service that loads a user's profile data and caches it. Such a service doesn't even need to know about logins, just the ID of the user it needs to load.

Comment: In a more Blazor-y way, you can load the user data in App.razor and pass it as a Cascading parameter down to all components, the same way [authentication state is passed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter). You can combine both approaches - make the profile service a dependency of App.razor and pass *some* properties as cascading parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so if I add properties to IdentityUser, populate them in the Identity login, this will be carried over to the Blazor Server app? I assumed EF was using that model to map against the AspNetUsers database table and overwriting the object each time it reads it from the db.

Comment: See this answer which shows how to add custom data to the ClaimsPrincipal object in the `AuthenticationStateProvider`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075629/how-do-i-add-custom-claims-to-a-claimsprincipal-after-authentication-in-a-net-6 .  Where you get the data from is up to you

Answer (score -1):

based on  Panagiotis Kanavos's suggestion,I tried another solution with CircuitHandler

```
internal sealed class UserCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler, IDisposable
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider;
    private readonly UserData userService;

    public UserCircuitHandler(
        AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider,
        UserData userService)
    {
        this.authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged +=
            AuthenticationChanged;

        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void AuthenticationChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        _ = UpdateAuthentication(task);

        async Task UpdateAuthentication(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
        {
            try
            {
                var state = await task;
                
                // 

                
                // do something based on claims
                userService.SomeUserData = true;

            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var state = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        

        // do something based on claims
        userService.SomeUserData = true;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -=
            AuthenticationChanged;
    }
}
```

Register it :

```
builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<CircuitHandler, UserCircuitHandler>());
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm on .Net6, not sure if that is different. I've tried this and it's still coming out as False. I think the app.UseMiddleware<PostAuthenticationMiddleware>(); isn't doing what I think it's doing. But if not, where do I hook into the user being logged in?

Comment: There is no HttpContext in Blazor Server.

Comment: If I could double-downvote, I would. `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.RequestServices.GetService<UserData>()` is a less reliable way of just writing `@inject UserData`. The scope lifetime remains the same, but since Blazor Server *doesn't* behave the same as ASP.NET Core, there may not be a current HttpContext.

Comment: Hi,@
Jay Walks,based on Panagiotis Kanavos's suggestion,I tried another solution with CircuitHandler

Comment: @RuikaiFeng that might work...