RBAC in ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm currently working on extracting the login ID from a JWT token and then fetching the roles associated with that login ID from the database. Once the roles are retrieved, I add them to ClaimTypes.Role using:
caimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

I can see the relevant claims being generated in context.User. However, when I use [Authorize(Role = "Admin")] on a controller, it still allows access to APIs even for users who do not have the required role.
Does anyone know why the authorization is not working as expected?
I've tried manually checking user claims within each method of my controller, and it correctly returns Forbidden when the Admin role is not present in the claims. However, when I use the [Authorize(Role = "Admin")] attribute on the controller, it doesn't work as expected, and users without the Admin role can still access the APIs.
Middleware:
var roles = await roleService.GetRolesAsync(username); // extracts role from rolec.cs 

var claimsIdentity = context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; 

foreach (var role in roles) 
{ 
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)); 
} 

context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);


I think you should be creating a new ClaimsIdentity instance and adding it to the existing context.User.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075629/how-do-i-add-custom-claims-to-a-claimsprincipal-after-authentication-in-a-net-6

When you call this middelware? between the app.UseAuthentication();  and
app.UseAuthorization();?

after app.Useauthentication and before app.UseAuthorisation

OK please share a reproduce sample with us for the codes to let us reproduce the issue
